# How Can I write Geopackage Layers with Abstract/Description/Metadata using QgsVectorFileWriter

Tags: pyqgis, metadata, geopackage

How can I use the QgsVectorFileWriter to include metadata description for Geopackage layers in a python script?

I can set the layer name using:

```
options.layerName = "roads_layer"
```

what I want is something like:

```
options.description = 'This are the roads covering such and such, Dec 2019".
```

In QGIS you can right click, export layer to Geopackage and you get the option to set a Description.

[image]

Then in QGIS, you get the description showing in the Abstract (baring in mind my examples don't actually match):

[image]

I can see that the GDAL Geopackage definition means you can do this, I just haven't been able to find or understand how to do it.

[image]
https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/gpkg.html

Can anyone help please?

Code:

```
layObj.setAbstract("Test metadata Dec 2019") # this line doesn't translate to the geopackage table
options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
options.actionOnExistingFile = QgsVectorFileWriter.CreateOrOverwriteLayer
options.layerName = layname
writer = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layObj, geopP, options)
```

Comment: I don't know how to implement it in _pyqgis_, but you need to write the value of the _'description'_ field, in the _'gpkg_contents'_ table for the row corresponding to your table, at the GeoPackage cointained database.

Comment: At least, that is what the `DESCRIPTION` creation option does. But what you see in the Abstract is a [Metadata Property](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#metadata-properties).

Comment: Thanks but I was hoping to avoid requiring two methods for exporting the data. Pyqgis and perhaps sqlite3.  If someone could confirm it's not possible in pyqgis that would be good to know.

Comment: Do you want to write the abstract metadata of the layer in the project or the description field of the gpkg_contents table of the layer file?

Comment: Most important is the description field of the gpkg contents table as it should be permanently present irrespective of software platform. In any case, qgis will read that Description and auto-populate the metadata abstract as I had in my post.  I've just tested in ArcMap and it doesn't show in the Layer Description but adding layer info with arcpy is easy.

Comment: I think that you are already writing it with `options.description`. I don't understand why you think that QGIS will populate the abstract metadata with that value.

Comment: "options.description" is made-up  as I prefixed it with "what I want is something like:". It's not a property of the vectorwriter but I was looking for something as simple as that.

Comment: Have you tested it?  because setting "Description" with the right click Save Vector Layer (see first screenshot) in the QGIS GUI does auto-populate the Metadata Abstract. If you test it you will see.  I need a python method that recreates this functionality if the vectorwriter doesn't support it.

Comment: No, what I have tested is write the description field in a gpkg_contents table and load the referenced layer in QGIS, and the value stored was not added to the Abstract Metadata tag.

Comment: Interesting, what version of QGIS are you using?  I'm using 3.8.0.  Maybe you can try the export layer using the GUI to see if it still doesn't show.

Comment: I was using QGIS LTR 3.4.13. Now in QGIS 3.10.0 yes, the project updates the metadata tag from the description value, in both cases manually stored in the database and filled in the export GUI.

Comment: So the problem simplifies to how to use the DESCRIPTION creation option of the GDAL GeoPackage driver from pyqgis, and load the layer in not 3.4 version :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `layerOptions` to add creation options. `layerOptions` is a list of strings formated as 'KEY=VALUE'.

Hence, embedding a layer description in the geopackage just comes to adding

```
options.layerOptions = ["DESCRIPTION=This are the roads covering such and such, Dec 2019"]
```

Here is a generic function which saves a layer into a geopackage and uses the layer's abstract as description in the geopackage.

```
def save_with_description(layer, outputfile):
    options = QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()

    # If geopackage exists, append layer to it, else create it
    if os.path.exists(outputfile):
        options.actionOnExistingFile = QgsVectorFileWriter.CreateOrOverwriteLayer
    else:
        options.actionOnExistingFile = QgsVectorFileWriter.CreateOrOverwriteFile

    # Use input layer abstract and name in the geopackage
    options.layerOptions = [f"DESCRIPTION={layer.abstract()}"]
    options.layerName = layer.name()
    return QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(layer, outputfile, options)
```

Comment: It works -Fabulous! Many thanks Yoann, I had a feeling it was easy- always struggle to find the documentation for that though